# Remove leading 10-digit number from filenames

Tags: linux, shell, command-line

I have thousands of image files that have a 10-digit number appended to the beginning of the filenames. Immediately following each string of 10 numbers is an underscore. They look like this:

```
1318487644_IMG_2158.jpg
```

I need to remove the 10dig number and the underscore, without disturbing what follows, the result of which should look like this:

```
IMG_2158.jpg
```

I'm using this command to find/replace other unwanted stuff in the filenames:

```
ls -1 | while read file; do new_file=$(echo $file | sed s/foo/bar/g); mv "$file" "$new_file"; done
```

How can I edit the above command to remove the leading 10dig+underscore combo(s) without altering the rest of the filename(s)?

Comment: Why not just use the standard `rename` command?

Comment: @EEAA: `rename` is only standard in Linux.

Comment: @cuonglm Right, and the question is tagged with "linux".

Comment: @EEAA: You should mention it explicitly, otherwise there's a chance that other persons can confuse.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Parsing `ls` output is considered bad practise by some. So it could look something like this (assuming posix shell):

```
for file in /path/to/file/*
do
    part_to_remove=$(echo "$file" | grep -Eo '[[:digit:]]{10}_')
    if ! [ -z $part_to_remove ]; then
        new_file="${file#$part_to_remove}"
        mv "$file" "new_file"
    fi 
done
```

Answer (score 0):

POSIXly:

```
for f in ./*; do
  mv -- "$f" "${f#./[0-9]*_}"
done
```